# How to efficiently randomize a relatively small array of all the same floats preserving the sum total?

Tags: javascript, math

How to efficiently randomize a relatively small array of all the same floats preserving the sum total?

For example:

I have an array of equal floats:

```
[ 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 ] // sum === 0.5
```

I want to randomize it like this:

```
[ 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.15, 0.05 ] // sum === 0.5
```

The initial array is always of equal values but it could be in various ranges:

```
[ 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56 ]
```

I dont know the actual size these initial arrays will end up being but I'm guessing they will be between 50 to 100 items in length.

(FYI: These are note durations, bonus points if the algorithm is musical)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Calculate n random floats between 0 and 1

2) Calculate the sum of these n numbers.

3) You have to divide the sum with itself and multiply it with the sum you want to get (in the following the resultsum). So if you divide every of the n numbers generated in 1) with the sum calculated in 2) and multiply the result with the resultsum, then you get the random numbers you want in your result.

Comment: This is quite efficient so far, still testing.

Comment: I've gone with this answer seeing as it's more efficient, it doesn't do an additional sort, and has fewer loops.

Comment: Note on step #3: If you have to divide the sum with itself you always get 1, hence you only need the sum you want to get. So step 3 is "So you divide every of the n numbers generated in 1 with the sum calculated in 2 and multiply the result with expected sum"

Answer (score 2):

Not musical but:

1) Calculate the sum of all values in the array.

2) Generate N-1 points between 0 and sum, where N is the number of entries in the array.

3) Order these N-1 points from smallest to greatest, then augment the array with 0 on the left and sum on the right. Basically, imagine that you've taken a bar of `sum` length and chopped it at N-1 points.

4) For each element in the now N+1 points (excluding the first), calculate its difference between it and the previous point. The sum of these differences is still `sum` - you can prove this to yourself by imagining the chopped up bar's pieces being the differences. If you cut a bar of length 1 at 0.2 and 0.7, then you augment to get 0,0.2,0.7,1.0 and the differences are 0.2, 0.5, 0.3 which sum to 1.

5) Shuffle the output of 4) randomly (Fisher-Yates shuffle if you need to implement it)

---

If you wanted to make it musical, you might want to 'discretify' step 2, by which I mean something like:

a) divide the first element of array by 2 (call this D) (e.g. 0.1/2 = 0.05)

b) divide sum by D (call this Sd) (e.g. 0.5/0.05 = 10)

c) create your random numbers from 0 to Sd as integers, then multiply them by D

d) now continue from 3 in the original algorithm

This will give you only semiquavers. If you use 4 instead of 2 you get semidemiquavers, and so on

Comment: Trying to code these to pick an answer, sort of getting lost on the calculations at #4

Comment: This is not really a solution. In step 2) you pick N random points between 0 and sum, but you dont necesserily have to pick 0 and sum itself. In step 4) you calculate the sum of the differences and assume that this is still sum. But it is only true, if you have 0 and sum in your N chosen points. If at least one of them was not chosen, then the sum of the N points is NOT sum and with this the calculation fails. But if you always choose 0 and sum as points for the N points in 2), then you are not random anymore.

Comment: @user2248673 Thanks for the feedback, I've edited the solution to be more accurate and clearer. Let me know if you have any more feedback

Comment: I picked the other answer, but nonetheless gave you the bonus point :)

Comment: @Quickredfox np, user2248673's answer is conceptually simpler